# Loop through column value and insert into another table

Tags: sql-server

I have the following pseudo code and want to know if I am going about it properly. The background is I have a table that has ~138 million rows in it and I want to aggregate certain certain columns by some set of grouping variables. I want to do this on the [Timestamp] column which represents a snapshot date. There are roughly 4 million rows per snapshot.

```sql
DECLARE @Timestamp DATETIME;

DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR SELECT [Timestamp] FROM dbo.my_table;

OPEN cursor_name;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO @Timestamp;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT A.[Timestamp],
        A.Column2,
        A.Colmn_N,
        [agg_val_1] = ...,
        [agg_val_n] = ...
    INTO dbo.my_aggregate_tbl
    FROM dbo.my_table AS A
    WHERE A.Timestamp = @Timestamp
    GROUP BY A.[Timestamp],
        A.Column2,
        A.Column_N;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO @Timestamp;
END

CLOSE cursor_name;

DEALLOCATE cursor_name;
```

Is what I have a usable way to achieve this? There are roughly 30 distinct timestamps.

Comment: most definitely not a cursor.  use a SELECT with GROUP BY.

Comment: Why not just aggregate without cursor? `SELECT A.[Timestamp],A.Column2,A.Colmn_N,[agg_val_1] = ...,[agg_val_n] = ... INTO dbo.my_aggregate_tbl FROM dbo.my_table AS A GROUP BY A.[Timestamp],A.Column2,A.Column_N;` Unless you're paid per line, in which case, go ahead

Comment: A few reasons, it seems to take longer then the more timestamps you add, as in the time does not seem to run linear and I've never written a cursor.

Comment: @smoore4 none of this has anything to do with my question. If you don't like my question then just ignore it.

Comment: `DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR SELECT [Timestamp] FROM dbo.my_table;` this will loop every 138 million rows, so i'm pretty sure the non-cursor code will be able to beat a 138mil x 138 rows aggregation code. But if it doesn't, please come back when it's finished with your findings. Can you explain what you're actually trying to do? Do you want to aggregate just some of timestamps in your table?

Comment: I want to aggregate over the timestamps of which there are 30, there are roughly 4 million rows per timestamp to aggregate

Comment: you want to do SUM(agg_val_1) or COUNT(agg_val_1) AVG, MAX, etc.  you didn't specify the aggregation that you are looking to do.

Comment: Your right I didn't as I didn't think it would add anything, it's just simple sum()'s

Comment: then it is this:  SELECT A.[Timestamp], A.Column2, A.Colmn_N, SUM([agg_val_1])
INTO dbo.my_aggregate_tbl
FROM dbo.my_table AS A
GROUP BY A.[Timestamp], A.Column2, A.Column_N;

Comment: the downvotes are people seeing RBAR used for Set Theory

Comment: That I understand but there are about 4 million rows per timestamp for a total of 138 million rows and time does not scale linear. A single timestamp takes about 2 minutes while letting all 30 go, either bombs the server out of memory or runs for hours, that's why I thought some sort of loop would work

Comment: Just index your table properly then a sort is not needed `(Timestamp, Column2, Column_N) INCLUDE (OtherColumnsHere)`

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the reason your regular aggregation code is slow because there's not enough memory/log space/temp db sort space to perform the whole thing at once and that you're batching operations per timestamp.

First, you then need to get `DISTINCT timestamp` codes for your cursor, ie. `DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY LOCAL STATIC FOR SELECT DISTINCT [Timestamp] FROM dbo.my_table;` Otherwise it's gonna loop forever.

Then, you need to avoid `INTO dbo.my_aggregate_tbl` because it will crash on second loop iteration. Better to create my_aggregate_tbl by CREATE TABLE ... and then INSERT into it.

Finally, i still think the straight up aggregation code will beat the cursor, since that will use just one scan, but maybe you have index on timestamp but not enough memory, in that case, it might work, but i doubt it very much.

The reason it runs non-linearly can be many, probably it runs out of memory and have to pre-aggregate things. You could create an indexed view which might improve things, and avoids aggregating things on the fly.

Comment: Yes I may run into out of memory, I could have clarified that in my original ask. I can create the table beforehand and dump into it, that is not an issue